# General formula for the $2K\pi$th roots of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am working on integrating trigonometric functions with modulus in them. For that, I somehow found a hint and possibly need the $2K\pi$th roots of unity where $K$ is an integer. I'm accepting all values (As in, complex as well, but I have a gut feeling that complex numbers which aren't purely real will be more helpful, because $1$ didn't work.)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by root of unity. [the usual usage of this term is restricted to n-th roots for positive integers n.]

Comment: My bad. I meant 1^(1/2kpi)

Comment: Al F.: It seems like what you are trying to ask about is what is usually called the "$2k$-th roots of unity, where $k$ is a positive integer. That is, the even roots of unity. These are usually not written in the 1 raised to a fractional power. Even though say $2^{\frac12}$ is sometimes written for $\sqrt{2}.$